# Will epoll notify all processes listening on the same fd?

Tags: linux, io, epoll

I've multiple subprocesses `fork()`ed that's listening on the same fd set.

Will all of them be notified or only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

They should all be notified unless one of them acts on the ready file descriptors and makes them no longer ready while another one is busy (not waiting in epoll, so "misses" the notification).

Comment: is there any reference?If that's the case,it's going to cause `thundering herd` ,right?

Comment: Yeah, the thundering herd thing is a problem.  You probably shouldn't do this, for that and other reasons.  I don't have a formal reference handy, but if it were me I'd try it for myself and find out see how it goes.  Or maybe better just to re-architect now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, events will be triggered in both processes. But if you use EPOLLET, race condition may occur.